# How to create a Folder by giving command to chatbot?

Tags: dialogflow-es

User can give the input command to create a folder and chatbot automatically build folder in the PC?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a webhook with [fulfillment](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-overview) that has access to your file system.

1. First detect the intent to build a folder as you normally would.
2. Enable fulfillment on the intent so that your webhook can be triggered.
3. The triggered function can then generate a folder (assuming it has access to your file system)